# Thread safe data structure in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, mutex

Like to make a thread safe C++ data structure as follows.

```
struct infos{
  int crowdinfos[10][horGridNums*verGridNums];
  int cameraSourceID;
  static int idx;
  std::mutex mutex;
  
};
```

mutex.lock and unlock will be used to be thread safe.

EDIT:
In my header file, I'll have a vector of infos.

```
std::vector<infos> c_infos;
```

When I build with g++, I have errors as

```
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_construct.h:75:7: error: use of deleted function ‘infos::infos(const infos&)’
     { ::new(static_cast<void*>(__p)) _T1(std::forward<_Args>(__args)...); }
       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from gstdsexample.cpp:29:0:
gstdsexample.h:66:8: note: ‘infos::infos(const infos&)’ is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
 struct infos{
        ^~~~~
gstdsexample.h:66:8: error: use of deleted function ‘std::mutex::mutex(const std::mutex&)’
```

The whole log infos in build are as follows.

```
-fPIC -DDS_VERSION="5.0.0" -I /usr/local/cuda-10.2/include -I ../../includes -pthread -I/usr/include/gstreamer-1.0 -I/usr/include/orc-0.4 -I/usr/include/gstreamer-1.0 -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/opencv4/opencv -I/usr/include/opencv4
g++ -c -o gstdsexample.o -fPIC -DDS_VERSION=\"5.0.0\" -I /usr/local/cuda-10.2/include -I ../../includes -pthread -I/usr/include/gstreamer-1.0 -I/usr/include/orc-0.4 -I/usr/include/gstreamer-1.0 -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/opencv4/opencv -I/usr/include/opencv4 gstdsexample.cpp
In file included from /usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_tempbuf.h:60:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_algo.h:62,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/algorithm:62,
                 from /usr/include/opencv4/opencv2/core/base.hpp:55,
                 from /usr/include/opencv4/opencv2/core.hpp:54,
                 from /usr/include/opencv4/opencv2/imgproc.hpp:46,
                 from /usr/include/opencv4/opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp:48,
                 from gstdsexample.h:30,
                 from gstdsexample.cpp:29:
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_construct.h: In instantiation of ‘void std::_Construct(_T1*, _Args&& ...) [with _T1 = infos; _Args = {const infos&}]’:
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:83:18:   required from ‘static _ForwardIterator std::__uninitialized_copy<_TrivialValueTypes>::__uninit_copy(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, _ForwardIterator) [with _InputIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const infos*, std::vector<infos> >; _ForwardIterator = infos*; bool _TrivialValueTypes = false]’
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:134:15:   required from ‘_ForwardIterator std::uninitialized_copy(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, _ForwardIterator) [with _InputIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const infos*, std::vector<infos> >; _ForwardIterator = infos*]’
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:289:37:   required from ‘_ForwardIterator std::__uninitialized_copy_a(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, _ForwardIterator, std::allocator<_Tp>&) [with _InputIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const infos*, std::vector<infos> >; _ForwardIterator = infos*; _Tp = infos]’
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_vector.h:331:31:   required from ‘std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::vector(const std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>&) [with _Tp = infos; _Alloc = std::allocator<infos>]’
gstdsexample.cpp:444:40:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_construct.h:75:7: error: use of deleted function ‘infos::infos(const infos&)’
     { ::new(static_cast<void*>(__p)) _T1(std::forward<_Args>(__args)...); }
       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from gstdsexample.cpp:29:0:
gstdsexample.h:66:8: note: ‘infos::infos(const infos&)’ is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
 struct infos{
        ^~~~~
gstdsexample.h:66:8: error: use of deleted function ‘std::mutex::mutex(const std::mutex&)’
In file included from /usr/include/c++/7/mutex:43:0,
                 from /usr/include/opencv4/opencv2/core/utility.hpp:62,
                 from /usr/include/opencv4/opencv2/core.hpp:3291,
                 from /usr/include/opencv4/opencv2/imgproc.hpp:46,
                 from /usr/include/opencv4/opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp:48,
                 from gstdsexample.h:30,
                 from gstdsexample.cpp:29:
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/std_mutex.h:97:5: note: declared here
     mutex(const mutex&) = delete;
```

What could be the correct way of using inside Struct?

Comment: You are missing the code where the problem actually occurs. Something is trying to make a copy of a `infos` object, but `std::mutex` is not copyable and so the implicit copy constructor is deleted. The error is wherever the copy is being made, not in the `infos` struct. `gstdsexample.cpp:444:40:   required from here` <-- this is where the problem is.

Comment: I made EDIT. I just have `std::vector<infos> c_infos;` inside header file. The sturcture with mutex and vector in header only and I get the error in build.

Comment: @batuman That line alone would not cause this error. The compiler output points to line 444 of `gstdsexample.cpp`. Can you show that line, as well as the surrounding context?

Comment: @cdhowie I c thanks. I have added to release memory as `std::vector<infos>(dsexample->c_infos).swap(dsexample->c_infos);`. Any problem for this?

Comment: @batuman `std::vector<infos>(dsexample->c_infos)` makes a copy of `dsexample->c_infos`. I have no idea why you'd construct a copy of a vector from a source and then swap the copy with that same source. That doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: Sorry  I need to do this `std::vector<infos>().swap(dsexample->c_infos);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you haven't posted your code entirely, I'm not sure what your problem is. So please look at my example below instead.

Here is how I use a mutex for a queue. By looking at it you can adapt your struct for whatever it is you are trying to accomplish.

```
class Queue {
public:
    Queue() = default;

    /**
     * Push a message to the queue.
     */
    void push(const std::array<int, 4>& message) {
        while (true) {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> locker(mu);
            cond.wait(locker, [this](){ return buffer_.size() < size_; });
            buffer_.push_back(message);
            locker.unlock();
            cond.notify_all();
            return;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Pop a message off the queue.
     */
    bool pop(std::array<int, 4>& value) {
        while (true) {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> locker(mu);
            if (buffer_.size() == 0) {
                return false;
            }
            value = buffer_.front();
            buffer_.pop_front();
            locker.unlock();
            cond.notify_all();
            return true;
        }
    }

private:
    std::mutex mu;
    std::condition_variable cond;

    std::deque<std::array<int, 4>> buffer_;
    const unsigned int size_ = 200;
    
};
```

In a nutshell, wherever you want thread safe access to some object do something like:

```
std::unique_lock<std::mutex> locker(mu);
            
//Add Your code on the object you want thread safe access to.

            locker.unlock();
            cond.notify_all();
```

The important thing is, that you only access the object you want thread safe access to within the locker / unlock as above, and that you notify anyone waiting on the object as described above.

Please see your error message:

```
‘infos::infos(const infos&)’ is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:  struct infos{
```

Comment: Hi I have updated in EDIT.  I just have std::vector<infos> c_infos; inside header file. So the sturcture with mutex and vector in header only and I get the error in build.

Comment: Sorry the error is coming from `std::vector<infos>(dsexample->c_infos).swap(dsexample->c_infos);` to release memory.

Comment: @batuman without seeing the full code, can't say really. Please see my updated answer for where you should be looking.

Comment: Thanks but I like ur suggestions above. I'll use that after solving error.

Comment: hi mutex locks slow down my process a lot. Is there any way to make data thread safe, but not slow down the process.

Comment: @batuman Any synchronization mechanism in any language has a performance implication. The alternative is to use "Atomics" (much less expensive). If you must use mutex, you can keep the code within the lock to a minimum. If you can use atomics, then it will be much less expensive. Another alternative is to avoid both mutex & atomics and see if you can redesign your code / app so that synchronization isn't necessary.

Comment: @batuman You can also you per-thread privatized copy of data. In this case there is no shared access, so each thread doesn't have to wait.

Comment: @batuman You can also partition your data, so that only a specific worker works on a range of data. If this is possible for your application, then it means that only one thread will ever contend for a specific piece of data meaning locking is unnecessary. The dataset will instead be divided amongst the threads, so you get the benefit of multithreading, without the cost of locking. Within each thread, a thread operates on requests in sequence. This works optimally when the processing time for each operation is the same - if the processing time varies, then requests on that thread may be blocked

Comment: @batuman Sure. If you have a specific question just post it on stackoverflow and I will answer it.

Comment: What's the purpose of the `while (true) { ... }` loop in each function?